# Optimise way to process 1 million records

Tags: python, for-loop, elasticsearch, optimization

I have almost 1 million items of data in Elastic search and I want to process each and every document with some NLP algorithm. The problem is my machine crashes again and again.

Is there any way to optimize dealing with this situation? Please help me.

TIA

Comment: A search engine like Elastic Search is the equivalent of a `filter` function. You need the equivalent of a `map` function.

Comment: Thanks, @chepner for your response. Can you please explain a bit with some examples?

Comment: @DavinderSingh You can go with parallel processing using Kafka and you also need to send documents through batch like every 1000 like that.

Comment: Why does the machine crash? Because of your NLP process or because of the Elasticsearch process (which I doubt)? Can you describe a bit more what you're doing?